# How do I move a div in the html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example if I have this html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two">this is the div i want to move</div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
</div>
```

How can I move the div with the id "two" after all the other divs so my html becomes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <div id="four"></div>
    <div id="two">this is the div i want to move</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the javascript/jQuery code you've tried?

Comment: This is just `$('.wrapper').append('#two')`, and shows no effort ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must work :

```
$("#two").appendTo(".wrapper");
```

This must also work :

```
$(".wrapper").append($("#two"));
```

[`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) are considered moving functions in jQuery. You must look at the docs more.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/gjJJe/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#two").appendTo(".wrapper")
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SbeDN/

Comment: @astex - they where posted seconds apart, no reason to downvote

Comment: @astex thats no reason to downvote..